# Method chaining with asyncio coroutines

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I want to implement [method chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17321241/1113207), but not for usual functions - for asyncio coroutines.

```
import asyncio


class Browser:
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def go(self):
        # some actions
        return self

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def click(self):
        # some actions
        return self
```

"Intuitive" way to call chain wouldn't work, because single method returns coroutine (generator), not self:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def main():
    br = yield from Browser().go().click()  # this will fail

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Correct way to call chain is:

```
br = yield from (yield from Browser().go()).click()
```

But it looks ugly and becomes unreadable when chain grows.

Is there any way to do this better? Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but if you just want to iterate methods on the object you can do that by setting them into a dict, or with `getattr`.

Comment: Sorry, you should to use the "ugly" way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created solution, that do a job close to the needed. Idea is to use wrapper for `Browser()` which uses `__getattr__` and `__call__` to collect action (like getting attribute or call) and return self to catch next one action. After all actions collected, we "catch" `yiled from wrapper` using `__iter__` and process all collected actions.

```
import asyncio


def chain(obj):
    """
    Enables coroutines chain for obj.
    Usage: text = yield from chain(obj).go().click().attr
    Note: Returns not coroutine, but object that can be yield from.
    """
    class Chain:
        _obj = obj
        _queue = []

        # Collect getattr of call to queue:
        def __getattr__(self, name):
            Chain._queue.append({'type': 'getattr', 'name': name})
            return self

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            Chain._queue.append({'type': 'call', 'params': [args, kwargs]})
            return self

        # On iter process queue:
        def __iter__(self):
            res = Chain._obj
            while Chain._queue:
                action = Chain._queue.pop(0)
                if action['type'] == 'getattr':
                    res = getattr(res, action['name'])
                elif action['type'] == 'call':
                    args, kwargs = action['params']
                    res = res(*args, **kwargs)
                if asyncio.iscoroutine(res):
                    res = yield from res
            return res
    return Chain()
```

Usage:

```
class Browser:
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def go(self):
        print('go')
        return self

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def click(self):
        print('click')
        return self

    def text(self):
        print('text')
        return 5


@asyncio.coroutine
def main():
    text = yield from chain(Browser()).go().click().go().text()
    print(text)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Output:

```
go
click
go
text
5
```

Note, that `chain()` doesn't return real coroutine, but object that can be used like coroutine on `yield from`. We should wrap result of `chain()` to get normal coroutine, which can be passed to any asyncio function that requires coroutine:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def chain_to_coro(chain):
    return (yield from chain)


@asyncio.coroutine
def main():
    ch = chain(Browser()).go().click().go().text()
    coro = chain_to_coro(ch)

    results = yield from asyncio.gather(*[coro], return_exceptions=True)
    print(results)
```

Output:

```
go
click
go
text
[5]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's still not particularly pretty, but you could implement a `chain` function that scales a little bit better:

```
import asyncio  

@asyncio.coroutine
def chain(obj, *funcs):
    for f, *args in funcs:
        meth = getattr(obj, f)  # Look up the method on the object
        obj = yield from meth(*args) 
    return obj

class Browser:
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def go(self, x, y):
        return self

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def click(self):
        return self


@asyncio.coroutine
def main():
        #br = yield from (yield from Browser().go(3, 4)).click()
        br = yield from chain(Browser(), 
                                ("go", 3, 4),
                                ("click",))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

The idea is to pass tuples in a `(method_name, arg1, arg2, argX)` format to the `chain` function, rather than actually chaining the method calls themselves. You can just pass the method names directly if you don't need to support passing arguments to any of the methods in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and wrote [quent](https://github.com/drukmano/quent) to handle these cases:

```py
from quent import ChainAttr

br = await ChainAttr(Browser()).go().click().run()
```

It also supports [method cascading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_cascading) without the class having to implement it itself (i.e. without `return self`):

```py
from quent import CascadeAttr

br = await CascadeAttr(Browser()).go().click().run()
```